# How can I copy a directory without all files appearing as "modified"?

Tags: git

I recently backed up a `.git` containing directory, in which I had some commits and some unstated changes.

When I open the backed up directory and perform a `git status`, all project files appear as `modified`.

I can't get it to the same state I backed it up, which is: Only files differing from last commit appearing as unstated/modified.

Any clues ?

Comment: What does `git diff` show to you?

Comment: If you're on windows it's likely different file permissions - `git diff` will tell you.

Comment: `Git diff`output all files as the same with no visible changes

Comment: Is there a difference in your AutoCRLF settings? Checked `git update-index` or `git update-index --refresh`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why all files are showing up as being modified.  But if we assume that this is a fluke and that these changes are not real or significant, then one way to solve your problem might be to do a `git reset`:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: Does this command take into account that I dont want to loose the unstaged (not commited) changes I had in my original directory ?

Comment: @lapin No, it resets everythig to HEAD, which is your last commit

Comment: I dont want to loose the not-commited changes !

Comment: Then you will need to find out why _everything_ is showing up as changed.  It could be due to permissions or line endings.  For future reference, please commit your work before backing up.